# Pexpect PopenSpawn does not show anything on stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pexpect

I wanted to try to use the Pexpect Python library and its `popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` function to create some cross-platform automation.

I started with something very simple and run it against Linux:

```py
import sys
from pexpect import popen_spawn

child = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("ls /", logfile=sys.stdout)
```

This shows nothing on the standard output, is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that was fairly easy, should have used `sys.stdout.buffer` instead of `sys.stdout` just like below:

```py
import sys

import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn


child = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("ls /", logfile=sys.stdout.buffer)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Which outputs correctly the content of `/`:

```
bin
boot
cdrom
dev
etc
home
initrd.img
initrd.img.old
lib
lib64
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
snap
srv
swapfile
sys
timeshift
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz
vmlinuz.old
```